# Django, jQuery, and autocomplete

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete

After some extensive research (Googling), I cannot find a current tutorial on how to set up autocomplete using Django and jQuery.  There appears to be a variety of plugins and there appears to be no consistency or standard about which to use or when.

I'm not a pro at either Django or jQuery, but need an autocomplete solution that is well documented and fairly simple to utilize.

Suggestions?

Comment: See: [Auto-Complete packages for Django](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/auto-complete/)

Answer (score 19):

If you're looking to search from within your django models then something like:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
    def autocompleteModel(request):
    search_qs = ModelName.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.REQUEST['search'])
    results = []
    for r in search_qs:
        results.append(r.name)
    resp = request.REQUEST['callback'] + '(' + simplejson.dumps(result) + ');'
    return HttpResponse(resp, content_type='application/json')
```

For the jQuery autocomplete and call:

```
function searchOpen() {
    var search = $('#txtSearch').val()
    var data = {
        search: search
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search.json',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'searchResult'
    });
}


function searchResult(data) {
    $( "#txtSearch" ).autocomplete ({
        source: data
    });
}
```

Finally to connect it all on your input form would have something like:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="txtSearch" onkeyup="searchOpen()" />
```

Note, this is using Jquery UI as well in addition to stock jQuery.

Comment: simplejson is deprecated and not available in latest Djangos: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/

Comment: Hi, can you explain where can i put the `/search.json` file?

Comment: I don't understand why people even try with django-autocomplete. I wasted about two hours trying to get it to work. This is much better and gives you much more control over your code.

Answer (score 7):

Meanwhile, a good tutorial appeared.

`autocomplete` does everything for you, all you have to do is the following:

**js**

```
$(function() {
  $("#search-field").autocomplete({
    source: "/ajax_calls/myFunction",
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^ajax_calls/myFunction/', 'my_app.views.handler_function'),
```

**views.py**

```
def get_drugs(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
        .....
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

**SOURCE:** 
http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/

Comment: Followed tutorial. Although results are returned, they don't show in the drop downdown under the input. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617931/jquery-ui-autocomplete-results-doesnt-show-in-html-dropdown

Comment: It took also a while for me to make it work, and an additional [question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42230622/5802289). Once I figured out how to do it, I tried to make a step-by-step explanation that will hopefully be useful for others.

Comment: If your input field- 'search-field' were inside a form, how'd you do it?

Comment: @GaneshJadhav - Have you been able to find answer to your query? I am facing a similar issue. Posted a query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59653139/12379095). It would be nice to get to know your take on this.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you want to set up autocomplete on some input field (like `<input type="text" id="id_input">`) with the username of your users. This is the way I did it:

**urls.py**

First of all, add a url that will be used by the AJAX call.

```
url(r'^ajax/autocomplete/$', views.autocomplete, name='ajax_autocomplete')
```

**views.py**

Then set a view to retrieve the information (i.e the usernames, in this case) from the database

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def autocomplete(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        username_query = request.GET.get('username_query', '')
        usernames = (User.objects
                     .filter(username__startswith=username_query)
                     .values_list('username', flat=True))
        data = {
            'usernames': usernames,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**JavaScript**

Finally, you need to make a JavaScript function that goes to the database and returns the usernames that match with the value of the input field every time you press (and release) a key. For this, we are going to use **Ajax**, **JQuery** and the **JQuery-ui**'s autocomplete function

```
jQuery(function() {
    $("#id_input").on('keyup', function(){
        let value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'ajax_autocomplete' %}",
            data: {
              'username_query': value 
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                let usernames = data.usernames;
                $("#id_input").autocomplete({
                source: usernames,
                minLength: 3 
                });       
            }
        });        
    });
  });
```

And that's it! For more information, you can check out this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of django-autocomplete: https://bitbucket.org/tyrion/django-autocomplete/wiki/Home .  Its got a nice plug-and-play and is very easy to integrate with your own apps without much additional coding.

Comment: I looked at django-autocomplete, and it seemed a good way to go.  I couldn't quite figure out how to integrate it into my form and template though.  The instructions don't go that far.

Answer (score 3):

I know that implementing jQuery autocomplete is tricky. Here is a working example for Django > 2.0:

Step 1: Create  a simple HTML with an input (Don't forget to add links to load jQuery and jquery-ui). Save the code as testsearch.html

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
</head>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="search"> Search </label>
  <input id="search">
</div>
```

Step 2: Add a JavaScript code to the html. It calls the function autocomplete from jquery-ui. This function uses a source which the URL for Ajax calls

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: "{% url 'project:ajax_load_project' %}",
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
</script>
```

Step 3: Now we need to create two functions.  A simple function to render testsearch.html and another one that receives Ajax calls and send back data.

```
def ajax_load_project(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        print(q)
        projects = Project.objects.filter(title__istartswith=q)[:5]
        results = []
        for project in projects:
            project_json = {}
            project_json['id'] = project.id
            project_json['value'] = project.title
            project_json['label'] = project.title
            results.append(project_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)

def searchProject(request):
    template = 'project/testsearch.html'
    return render(request, template)
```

Project is my model. You can replace it with your Model. Replace title with the field used for searching.

For my example you can create this simple Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    """
    A Model representing a the project.
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Step 4: Don't forget to include two URLs. One for the HTML and the one for Ajax calls

```
urlpatterns += [
    #test search
    path('SuggestProject/', views.ajax_load_project, name='ajax_load_project'),
    path('searchtest/', views.searchProject, name='searchProject'),]
```

Answer (score 1):

django-autocomplete-light is very nice option. It is very easy to use and also documented very well.
Link: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light

Documentation: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Nikhil Shirsath, The docs only show how to enable it for admin purposes. Is there a sample where I can see it for normal app rather than admin?

Comment: @user763410 Here is the link of the tutorial from django-autocomplete-light: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJIHiqWKUXI

Answer (score 1):

I find https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp tutorial to be good. The tutorial uses a static countries array from which the autocomplete function selects the responses(dropdown elements).

Now to make the same more dynamic we can add simple jQuery ajax call to a Django view.

```
var countries;
$.ajax({
    url : '/autocomplete_view';
    data : {'query':$('#query').val()};
    type : 'GET',
    success : function(response){
        countries = JSON.parse(response);
        // do something extra
    },
    failure : function(response){
        // do something here
    },
    async : false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way without using Json:

example: let's assume you have a model named College:

```
class College(models.Model):
    collegeName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.collegeName
```

Now, render a context named 'all_colleges' = College.objects.all() to your template,:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="college"/>
```

**JS:**

```
  $( function() {
    var availableColleges = [
      {% for clg in all_colleges %}
          "{{clg}}",
      {%endfor%}
    ];
    $( "#clg" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableColleges
    });
  } );
```

**Resources to be included in the template:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

That's it!

If you need autocomplete to show options which start with the term entered, modify the default filter autocomplete filter function by adding this snippet in your template:

```
 // over write the default autocomplete function to match the option starting with entered term 
  $.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
      return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
  };
```

Comment if you face any problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the simplest way to get started (although probably not the optimal for production) is with [JQuery Autocomplete Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

The most basic way just requires to copy-paste the code into your html, using an array as a `source`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Cities example</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Cities: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>

<script>
    $( function() {
      var availableTags = [
          'Barcelona',
          'Berlin',
          'London',
          'Madrid',
          'Rome',
          'Paris'
      ];
      $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    } );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.10 I use same code

url:

```
# Ajax
    url(r'^search-autocomplete/$', autocompleteModel,  name='search-autocomplete'),
```

view:

```
def autocompleteModel(request):
    search_qs = Account.objects.filter(email__startswith=request.GET['search'])
    results = []
    for r in search_qs:
        results.append(r.email)
    resp = request.GET['callback'] + '(' + simplejson.dumps(results) + ');'
    return HttpResponse(resp, content_type='application/json')
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function searchOpen() {
        var search = $('#countryId').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cabinet/search-autocomplete',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: injectCsrfToken({
                search: search
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                searchResult(data)
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error');
            }

        });
    }
    function searchResult(data) {
        console.log('sdfsdfd');
        $( "#countryId" ).autocomplete ({
            source: data
        });
    }
    $("#countryId").on('keyup', function () {
        searchOpen();
    });
});
```

html:

```
<input id="countryId" type="text" name="fname">
```