# How to Connect JQuery-UI Autocomplete Widget to Django-Dajax?

Tags: django, jquery-ui, autocomplete, dajaxice, dajax

I have a Django app for which I am trying to build an autocomplete UI for making selections.  As the user types into a text box and the the app should make search suggestions based on values retrieved from the database.  I want to use Dajax/Dajaxice to handle the ajax and the jquery-ui autocomplete widget for the UI template.  Can someone please explain how to get the jquery-ui autocomplete widget to call my dajax function via the autocomplete `source` attribute (or any other better way)?

My code is a combination of this [dajax example](http://www.dajaxproject.com/fullform/) and this [jquery-ui autocomplete example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote).

my_app/ajax.py:

```
from my_app.models import MyModel
from dajax.core import Dajax
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from django.utils import simplejson

@dajaxice_register
def auto_filter_selections(request, symbol):
    dajax = Dajax()
    result = MyModel.objects.filter(symbol__startswith = symbol)
    dajax.assign('#id_symbol', 'innerHTML', str(result))
    return dajax.json()
```

template: my_app_ui.html

```
<head>
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}dajax/jquery.dajax.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
....
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#id_symbol").autocomplete({
      source: "Dajaxice.ui.auto_filter_symbols(Dajax.process,'symbol':$('#id_symbol').serialize(true)});",
      minLength: 1 //We want to search for even one character
    });
  });
</script>
....
</head>

<body>
....
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="id_symbol">Symbol: </label>
  <input id="id_symbol">
</div>
....
</body>
```

If you notice above, I am using jquery-1.7.2 and jquery-ui-1.10.4.  This is because the [dajax documentation](http://django-dajax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) says it is compatible with jquery-1.7.2.  Not sure if I can use a newer jquery version.

I am not sure how to get the template's javascript to call my dajax function.  the jquery-ui [documentation for .autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) says to use its `source` attribute but does not give a very good example.  Can anyone tell me if the above is correct?

Once the dajax view function retrieves suggestions from the DB, how do I populate the `.autocomplete` text box with it?

I've done quite a bit of research over the past few days but there are few examples of Django-Dajax-JQueryUI applications out there.

Answer (score 0):

After considerably more research and piecing various clues together I finally found the key to getting the JQuery-UI autocomplete widget to work with Dajax/Dajaxice and Django.

Synopsis:

1. Initialize JQuery-UI .autocomplete's *source* option with a separate javascript (JQuery) setter function
2. Connect .autocomplete widget's *source* option to server-side function with a Dajaxice command via a third javascript function.

Explanation:

Firstly, it is important to remember that Dajaxice provides the ajax communication channel by which your client-side javascript and the server side code transact, whereas Dajax provides a convenient way of generating the javascript (JSON) code that will perform the desired function in the client browser without having to write any javascript.

Since JQuery-UI provides us with the javascript widget (in the form of jquery) to perform our desired function (*.autocomplete*), we do not need Dajax and will not, according to my findings, have any success with it in this application.  We ONLY need Dajaxice in order to connect the client side javascript (*.autocomplete*) to our server side function that does the searching and returns results to suggest to the user.

Below is my revised code that I have gotten working.  Note that I have only tested it on a development platform thus far.

**my_autocomplete_search_template.html** with extraneous code removed:

```
<head>
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}dajax/jquery.dajax.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
....
<script>
    //Initialize the source option of .autocomplete widget during page load
    //See: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-option setter example code
    var local_source = ["Abc",]  //Dummy string for initialization only; temporary value
    $("#search_box").autocomplete("option", "source", local_source)
</script>
<script>
    //.autocomplete widget is Dajaxice callback function
    // *data* comes from server-side function
    function search_result(data) {
        $("#search_box").autocomplete({
            source: data,
        });
    }
</script>
<script>
    //This function called by user <input> tag and calls the server-side function via Dajaxice command
    function dajax_filter_search_term() {
        Dajaxice.my_app.auto_filter_search_term(search_result,'search_term':$('#search_box').val()});
        //                  |                     |                  |      ----------------------
        //                  |                     |                  |                |
        //             server-side          .autcomplete      serverside          user-typed
        //              function           callback func.    func. argument      value to search
    }
</script>
....
</head>

<body>
....
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="search_box">Search Term: </label>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" onkeyup="dajax_filter_search_term()" />
</div>
....
</body>
```

**my_app/ajax.py**

```
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from django.utils import simplejson
from my_app.models import MyModel

@dajaxice_register
def auto_filter_search_term(request, search_term):
    # Query DB for suggestions to present to user
    q = MyModel.objects.filter(myfield__istartswith=search_term)
    data = []
    for item in q:
        # Format returned queryset data, if needed
        data_item = item.field1 + ', ' + item.field2 + ', ' + item.field3
        data.append(data_item)

    # Return data to callback function *search_result*
    return simplejson.dumps(data)
```

That is it!  The key is to initialize the .autocomplete source option first and to only use Dajaxice to communicate with the server-side function.

It is possible to optimize the client-side code further by getting rid of the javascript function *dajax_filter_search_term()* and including the Dajaxice call in the *#search_box* input tag like so:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" onkeyup="Dajaxice.ui.auto_filter_search_term(search_result, {'search_term':$('#search_box').val()})" />
```

**References**

- JQuery-UI API docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-option:
- Additional clues here:
  [Django, JQuery, and autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074329/django-jquery-and-autocomplete)