# jquery ui autocomplete results doesn't show in html dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

This is my django view ajax request function:

```
def get_town(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        towns = Town.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        results = []
        for name in towns:
            name_json = {}
            name_json['name'] = name.name
            results.append(name_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Urls and everything setup nicely.

My autocomplete is this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#id_town").autocomplete({
    source: "/api/get_town/",
    minLength: 3,
  });
});
```

However, you can see from image below that the results although is returned and available from the request, doesn't display in the dropdown. As per the entered keys in input box in the image below, the results I got was this: `[{"name": "Densuano"}]`

What's the problem then? Why isn't the dropdown showing?

[image]

Comment: not a solution, but this definitely helps you: ``data = json.dumps(list(Town.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).values('name')))``

Answer (score 2):

I figured out:

```
name_json['name'] = name.name
```

was the culprit. The above was making a key, value list which the autocomplete, somehow couldn't interpret. I changed to

```
name_json = name.name
```

and it worked.

Comment: have you tried my above solution in the comment? it's better than building your own list since you already have a mechanism