# How to suggest similar words in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an input field for locations with jquery-ui-autocomplete.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var location_input=$('input[id="location-autocomplete"]');
        var cityNames = [
            { value: 'Mallorca' },
            { value: 'Berlin' },
            { value: 'London' },
            // many other elements
        ];
        location_input.autocomplete({
          source: cityNames,
          minLength: 2
        });
      } );

    //   keeps same width as box
      jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._resizeMenu = function () {
          var ul = this.menu.element;
          ul.outerWidth(this.element.outerWidth());
        }
</script>
```

However, I am not happy with the case when the same location can have different names.

For example, let's say that the user wants to look for Mallorca. He could write: *Mallorca*, *Majorca*, *Palma de Mallorca*, *PMI* or *Palma*.

My first idea was to use the `label` property

```
var cityNames = [
    { value: 'Mallorca', label: 'Palma de Mallorca' },
    { value: 'Mallorca', label: 'Mallorca' },
    { value: 'Mallorca', label: 'Majorca' },
    // etc
    ];
```

However, this can be very confusing. Writing *Ma* the autocomplete would show *Mallorca*, *Palma de Mallorca* and *Majorca*, even if they are the same place.

[image: Autocomplete with three different names for the same place]

I would like that when typing *Ma* the user only gets one suggestion. Similarly, no matter if the user types *Maj*, *Mal* or *Pal*, he should just get only one suggestion term for Mallorca.

Ideally, an additional property called `input` working as the input keyword to be searched would have been perfect. Then, having an array with the properties `value` and `input` for each would have done the trick. Unfortunately, I did not find such a thing in the docs.

As you can see, I am using as source type an `array`. For what I read, maybe the `function` type would allow me to do something like this, but it is not clear to me how, as I am not very familiar with js and did not find any clear example about it.

How could I achieve that in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You can use  the `response` function ([see in API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response)) to remove the alternate spellings from the results. Also put the best spelling ("Mallorca" in this case) last. Check this out, I hope the comments are enough to get the logic. Try to type "Ma", or "Maj" and **select** the only option. In both cases it will display "Mallorca"

```js
 $( function() {
    var availableTags = [      
    { value: 'Mallorca', label: 'Palma de Mallorca' },
    { value: 'Mallorca', label: 'Majorca' },
    { value: 'Mallorca', label: 'Mallorca' },
    { value: 'Madrid', label: 'Madrid' }
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,      
      response: function( event, ui ) {
        var added = [];//Keep here the unique labels that are already in the list
        for(var i=ui.content.length-1;i>=0;i--){//Start a loop, itterate all items backwards
          var cur = ui.content[i].value;//Value of the item
          if($.inArray(cur,added)==-1){//If not already loaded
            added.push(cur);//Put the new item in the list
          }else{            
            ui.content.splice(i,1);//If already loaded remove it from the results
          }
        }        
      }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just saw it once I had figured out another way to do it. Anyway, your snippet seems to work and the solution is not for django only, as mine, so I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

After some additional research and many tries, I found a way to do it. This is **specific for Django**, so any other more generic proposal is of course more than welcome.

The solution is based on [this tutorial](http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/), although with some modifications.

---

First of all, import jQuery and jQueryUI in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Afterwards, in the template itself, you need to assign an id to the input tag. Note that this id is how jquery will identify in which form to run the autocomplete.

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="cities">City: </label>
  <input id="autocomplete-cities">
</div>
```

The javascript code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var location_input=$('input[id="autocomplete-city"]');
        location_input.autocomplete({
          source: "/api/get_city_names/",
          minLength: 2
        });
      } );

    //   keeps same width as box
      jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._resizeMenu = function () {
          var ul = this.menu.element;
          ul.outerWidth(this.element.outerWidth());
        }
</script>
```

And `urls.py` file needs to be modified accordingly:

```
# urls.py

import yourapp.views

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^api/get_city_names/', yourapp.views.get_city_names),
    ...,
]
```

And finally create the django view. The name of the function has to be the same as the one written in `urls.py` and the one written in the `source` of the javascript.

```
#views.py

import json

def get_city_names(request):

    #what was in the question an array is now a python list of dicts.
    #it can also be in some other file and just imported.
    all_city_names = [
    { good_name: 'Mallorca', input_name: 'Palma de Mallorca' },
    { good_name: 'Mallorca', input_name: 'Mallorca' },
    { good_name: 'Mallorca', input_name: 'Majorca' },
    # etc
    ]

    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')

        city_names = [c['good_name'] for c in all_city_names if q in c["input_name"]]
        city_names = set(city_names) #removing duplicates

        results = []
        for cn in city_names:
            cn_json = {'value': cn}
            results.append(cn_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

And the autocomplete should work.