# django 1.11 and jQuery autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, autocomplete

I have a form field which has input as gene name. It searches for gene name field in my model database gene_names. I need to autocomplete when users type the name. I was suggested to use jQuery. I searched and found following links

1. http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/

   2.[How to suggest similar words in autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224605/how-to-suggest-similar-words-in-autocomplete/42230622#42230622),

and others also...
 based on them i have writen following code. It doesnt gives any Error but it doesnt works.

**models.py**

```
class GeneList(models.Model):
gene_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**eg. of file uploading to database**[image: Screenshot of txt file with gene names]

**in base.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**In template file rendering form**

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>Gene Name &nbsp {{ form.gene_p }}</h4>
    <button type="submit">After giving gene name Click here!</button>
</form>
...
...<div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="genes">Gene: </label>
 <input id="id_gene_p"> <!-- id_gene_p because thats what inspect element 
   shows 
  id for Gene name form field -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var gene_input=$('input[id="id_gene_p"]');
    gene_input.autocomplete({
      source: "/filesapp/api/get_gene_names/",
      minLength: 2
    });
  } );
```

**id_gene_p because thats what inspect element shows id for Gene name form field**

**projects urls.py**

```
from filesapp import views
urlpatterns = [
...
...
url(r'^api/get_gene_names/', views.get_gene_names, name='get_genes'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from filesapp.forms import FileForm
from filesapp.models import GeneList
import csv
import json
...
def load_genes(file_path):
    #"this loads gene from file with gene name"
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_path))
    for row in reader:
        gene = GeneList.objects.create(gene_name=row[0])
        gene.save()

def get_gene_names(request):

    all_gene_names = GeneList.objects.all()

    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')

        gene_names = [g['good_name'] for g in all_gene_names if q in g["input_name"]]
        gene_names = set(gene_names) #removing duplicates

        results = []
        for gn in gene_names:
            gn_json = {'value': gn}
            results.append(gn_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

**And my forms.py file its not talked about in most of discussions**

```
from filesapp.models import GeneList
class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
gene_p = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs = { 'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Write the name of gene manipulated in above 
                 sample pairs. eg. Wnt',

        }
    ))
```

Please egarly waiting for any suggestions.
Or any errors you see.
And let me know if any other easier way is possible as i am new to it thus dont have much of a background.
And also if you need any more information required to solve this problem please let me know.
Thanks.

It's not working. I tried all the suggestion, nothings works.

Comment: try this once and check $.("#id_gene_p").autocomplete({
      source: "/filesapp/api/get_gene_names/",
      minLength: 2
    });

Comment: although it is not related to question bit you need not to call `gene.save()` just after your `GeneList.objects.create(gene_name=row[0])` call.

Comment: also as given in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224605/how-to-suggest-similar-words-in-autocomplete/42230622#42230622 all_city_name is a list of dictionary but here it is a queryset. so instead of `g['good_name']` and `g["input_name"]` try it with `g.good_name` and `g.input_name`

Comment: @Exprator tried it but it doesn't works.

Comment: @sasuke in reference stackoverflow.com/questions/42224605/... there seems to be two values fileds with are being used but in my case its just gene names thats all.

Comment: I wrote a small tutorial on how to use jquery autocomplete with Django. Maybe that will help.  
http://colinkingswood.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/automcomplete-in-django-search.html