# How can I implement keystroke live update from a database?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am developing a web app with a "search functionality", in the search functionality, I would like the app to display the database matches with every keystroke in the search field by the user. The picture below shows what I am trying to achieve.
[image]

I am developing with Python Django.

thanking you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I don't want to spend hours tackling this problem the wrong way. All I need is for someone to point me in the right direction and I will figure out every other thing myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not included by default of Django,
You should use a combination of jQuery or something like that, for example, you'll see it - http://www.lalicode.com/post/5/

Comment: @ATerry I would suggest that you see what the questioner wrote in a comment
, he is only looking for direction and not a solution to the code, and he certainly accepts this answer.
In addition, you can see an orderly answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074329/django-jquery-and-autocomplete?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
Thx.

Comment: @GavrielCohen suggesting jQuery isn't an answer. This answer is better suited as a comment.

Comment: @EliTrab Pls can you add/extend more explanation on your answer