# How to render an input field in a template bound to a model field in Django

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-templates, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The problem seems so solvable yet it eludes me. Hope I am able to explain my predicament.

I am trying to include a **jQuery** autocomplete in a form. The autocomplete itself is working fine. I am now trying to link it to a model which is something like this:

**models.py**

```
class SupplierCatchment(models.Model):
    supp = models.ForeignKey(Supplier.....)
    supp_area = models.ForeignKey(Country, ...)
    supp_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=150,...)
```

For rendering the form, I am using a **model form**.

**Case 1:**

In my template I am rendering the fields manually looping through the fields. For the **autocomplete** field, however I am using html input like this:

**Template**

```
.....
{% if field.name == "supp_area" %}
    <input type="text" id="supp_area" name="supp_area" placeholder="..."> <!-- My area of concern -->
{% else %}
    {{ field }}

....
```

During processing, the autocomplete field `id="supp_area"` picks up the values correctly from the `Country` model.

However on saving, I am able to save only the data entered in field `supp_remarks` and the **field** `supp_area` remains blank (*it is not a required field*).

**Case 2:**

I have tried to force field `id` using `attrs` in my **model form** like this (adapted from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.id_for_label)):

```
class CreateSuppAreaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    class Meta:
        model = SupplierCatchment
        fields = ('supp_area', 'supp_remarks')
        widgets = {
            'supp_area': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'country_search', 'placeholder': 'type...'}),   # 'id' being used in template autocomplete script
    ...
    ...
```

However, in this case I am getting the following **error**:

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
>   choices.

I find it **somewhat strange** given that both the model field `supp_area` and the jQuery autocomplete **view** are referring to the same FK model `Country`.

**What is needed to be done** so that the **input field** `id="supp_area"` value is saved. I would personally like to use the **Case 1**.

## Edit:

## The jQuery Code

```
<script>
    $( "#supp_area" ).autocomplete({
        source: "{% url 'country_search' %}",
        minLength: 2,
//      delay: 20,
    });
</script>
```

## The URL

```
path('country_search/', CountrySearch, name='country_search'),
```

Comment: Can you provide your jQuery code?  This looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  Instead of trying to modify Django's forms to work with jQuery, it would be much easier to modify the jQuery to work with the forms.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica - Provided.