# Having a list of autocomplete options in Django form CharField

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django form with two CharFields. I want users to be able to type but I want autocomplete suggestions based on the values in the database. Here is an example of what I want pulled from another website.[image: Form autocomplete]

This is what I am currently doing.

```
albums = Album.objects.values_list('artist', flat=True).distinct()
artists = Album.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()

class MakeGuess(forms.Form):
   artist = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='',
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Artist'}))
   album = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='',
                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Album'}))
```

The goal is to have the autocomplete dropdown for the artist field be the artists list and same for the albums. I tried to use a forms.TypedChoice field with choices=artists but it did not do what I thought it would.

Comment: Since data in your database can change while typing in your form field, i'd suggest you implement the autocomplete with an ajax call or something similar. There are also some libraries for django that solve [autocomplete](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/auto-complete/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django, jQuery, and autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074329/django-jquery-and-autocomplete)

Comment: What about using existing modules and django packages? https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/